# How can I create a function of login test case in selenium web driver- python & how I can call it in other test case?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python

How I can create a function of the login test case in selenium web driver- python and how I can call it in other test cases?

basically I want to call my login test case in other test cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_first(self):
        self.login("username1", "password1")

    def test_second(self):
        self.login("username2", "password2")

    def login(self, username, password):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

With pytest, create a fixture for login in conftest.py

In conftest.py file,

```
@fixture(scope = 'function')
def login(*args):
  <login_code>
```

In test files,

```
def test_home_page_icon(login):
    login()
    <test, verification code>
```

If you are not using pytest,you can import the login function in test file and call the function in test file.